# @Output and custom events don't work

Tags: html, angular, events, binding

I'm new in Angular and try pass data between child and parent component.

In child component.ts

```
@Output() doubleClick = new EventEmitter<string>();

onDoubleClick(nameAccount: string){
   this.doubleClick.emit(nameAccount);
}
```

child component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreateAccount(accountName.value, status.value)" (dblclick)="onDoubleClick(accountName.value)">
```

In parent component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  accounts = [
    {
      name: 'Master Account',
      status: 'active'
    },
    {
      name: 'Testaccount',
      status: 'inactive'
    },
    {
      name: 'Hidden Account',
      status: 'unknown'
    }
  ];

  nameAccount = '';

  onAccountAdded(newAccount: {name: string, status: string}) {
    this.accounts.push(newAccount);
  }

  onStatusChanged(updateInfo: {id: number, newStatus: string}) {
    this.accounts[updateInfo.id].status = updateInfo.newStatus;
  }

  afeterDoubleClicked(name: string) {
    this.nameAccount = name;
  }
}
```

In parent component.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <app-new-account (accountAdded)="onAccountAdded($event)"></app-new-account>
        <hr>
        <app-account *ngFor="let acc of accounts; let i = index" [account]="acc" [id]="i" (statusChanged)="onStatusChanged($event)"></app-account>
    </div>
</div>
<p (doubleClick)="afeterDoubleClicked($event)">This is paragraph {{nameAccount}}</p>
```

In Console don't show any error, when I click button information from child isn't display in paragraph. I don't know how to properly use debuger and maybe someone tell me why property isn't emmit?

Comment: can you post total parent code?

Comment: @Jonnysai I edit and add all code in parent component.ts

Comment: I think you need square brackets around [doubleClick].  I'd stick to chemistry if I were u walter ;)

Comment: add parent component.html total file

Comment: @Jonnysai i add all file

Comment: @getbucks when i change to square brackets i have error "Can't bind to 'doubleClick' since it isn't a known property of 'p'."

Comment: is "app-new-account" your child component?

Comment: @Jonnysai Yes "app-new-account" is my child component, this mean i should in this place that property that emit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add (doubleClick) output emitter to your child component

```
<app-new-account  (doubleClick)="afeterDoubleClicked($event)"(accountAdded)="onAccountAdded($event)"></app-new-account>
```